# Reference ngFor value in component

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a nested `ngFor` statement. I need to retrieve the value of my first `ngFor` on button click.

I have tried the following:

- use template reference variable
- use attribute binding
- use Input decorator

This is my code:

```html
<mat-expansion-panel  *ngFor="let item of Datasource;">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header  style="display:flex" class="mat-row">
    {{item.Header}}

  </mat-expansion-panel-header>

  <mat-selection-list [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions">
    <mat-list-option  *ngFor="let line of item.match;  let i= index;" [value]="line">
      <div class="container-name">
        <div class="col-6">{{i}} - {line.user.Name }}  vs {{ line.user.Address }}</div>

    </mat-list-option>
  </mat-selection-list>

  <div style="text-align:center; padding: 20px">
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="submit()" type="submit">Add</button>
  </div>

</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Did you try `(click)="submit(item)"`?

Comment: Yes I did. It passes the object but then whatever manipulation I tried to do using that object It affects the list from the template.  I want to retrieve the item and save into a basket. 
However when I reinitialise a child object in the new basket array it affects the <item> object. Hence my original list loses all of its content

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to clone that object properties first. As that object is linked to the template, when you manipulate it, it is manipulated on template too. You can use `var obj = Object.assign({}, actual obj)` and then do the manipulation on obj instead of actual one. Then it will not get affected in template. Hope it helps.